# Is Camera.Preview Callback inefficient due to GC Malloc calls on every frame?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-camera

GC Malloc is called on every frame when Camera.preview callback is running. I'm assuming that this adds to to slowness of myframe rate.

Does anybody have any advice on ways to reduce these calls. I've tried searching on google groups and there does not seem to be many response, so I wanted to get information from people who are building and using camera preview in their applications.

As GC Malloc is being called it seems a new piece of data is being used each time to hold a frame. Can this be predefined? - Is this what callbackwithBuffer does? Ive had trouble getting my head around this and have been unable to implement the callback with buffer properly so any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Also could someone fully explain what is happen in memory with the frames when camera preview running.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is an issue in older versions of android where memory is allocated and garbage collected in short span of time causing performance bottlenecks .

Explanation can be found here:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2794

Your issue can be fixed by using some hidden methods. However you need to expose them by using reflection (the bug link has further examples).

If I recall correctly this issue has been fixed in Froyo.

Comment: Well... This bootleneck appears in my Android 4.3 and 4.4 (Google Nexus 4) too... I'm able to achive about 10 fps using opencv without any processing, just returing recived frame. Maybe i should try setPreviewWithBuffer... What do you think?